# hector_exploration_controller publishs twist really slowly

Tags: ros, stage-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 Hello everyone,
    I try to use `hector_exploration_node` and `hector_exploration_controller` to let robot explore the unknown environment in the stage_ros.
    I simulate the environment by `stage_ros` and create the map by `gmapping` .

    The problem is that I can get the topic `/exploration_path` published by `hector_exploration_node` , but no goals topic . And  there is a trajectory from the robot to the unknown environment .
But the robot only rotate and cant move forward. And the  it costs `hector_exploration_node` 20 more seconds every cycle.
```

I also find similar problems [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/206391/some-problem-about-the-hector-exploration-control/).

```
Here is the rviz.
```

[image: image description]

So , please give me some advice.
Thanks first!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218279/hector_exploration_controller-publishs-twist-really-slowly/) by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2015-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The hector_exploration_controller is meant as a demo showcasing how the exploration approach can be used. It uses a slightly modified version of the [path follower originally available in navigation_experimental](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental/tree/hydro-devel/pose_follower). For demoing wih a simulated 6 wheel vehicle in Gazebo it worked fine for me, but you might have to play with the parameters a bit. See also [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/193031/problem-with-hector-navigation/) that seems to describe the same problem.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-09-28**:
Stefan, thanks for your answer. My robot is not a wheeled robot but a tracked robot. My colleague wonder if that's the point? Now we try to change the type of twist published by `hector_exploration_controller`.

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-09-28**:
Another question is that the tracked robot that Team Hector used in 2015 Robocup Rescue is a automatically one or a half-auto one?